# Providing a very large argument to a jq command to filter on keys

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

I am trying to parse a very large file which consists of JSON objects like this:

```
{"id": "100000002", "title": "some_title",  "year": 1988}
```

Now I also have a very big list of ID's that I want to extract from the file, if they are there.

Now I know that I can do this:

```
jq '[ .[map(.id)|indices("1", "2")[]] ]' 0.txt > p0.json
```

Which produces the result I want, namely fills p0.json with only the objects that have "id" 1 and "2". Now comes the problem: my list of id's is very long too (100k or so). So I have a Python programm that outputs the relevant id's. My line of thought was, to first assign that to a variable:

```
 REL_IDS=`echo python3 rel_ids.py`
```

And then do:

```
jq --arg ids "$REL_IDS" '[ .[map(.id)|indices($ids)[]] ]' 0.txt > p0.json
```

I tried both with brackets `[$ids]` and without brackets, but no luck so far.

My question is, given a big amount of arguments for the filter, how would I proceed with putting them into my jq command?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the list of ids is long, the trick is NOT to use `--arg`.  However, the details will depend on the details regarding the "long list of ids".

In general, though, you'd want to present the list of ids to jq as a file so that you could use `--rawfile` or `--slurpfile` or some such.

If for some reason you don't want to bother with an actual file, then provided your shell allows it, you could use these file-oriented options with process substitution: `<( ... )`

### Example

Assuming ids.json contains a lising of the ids as JSON strings:

```
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

then one could write:

```
< objects.json jq -c -n --slurpfile ids ids.json '
  inputs | . as $in | select( $ids | index($in.id))'
```

Notice the use of the `-n` command-line option.

Comment: Hi @peak, thanks for your reply. I definitely can provide a file: i have a txt file which has all the id's in the following form

`head -c 100 ids.txt` --> "1", "2", "3", "4" ... 

So if I understood correctly, if I will use `--rawfile rel_ids ids.txt` then it can be accessed like `indices($rel_ids)` in the indeces syntax?